# Closing an image window displays another window. Why?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm stuck. My code sucks. My silders don't work either, but the infinite image windows are driving me nuts. When I close the namedWindow, it opens a new display window with the image (infinitely). Help?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from pylepton import Lepton

#setup the Lepton image buffer
def capture(device = "/dev/spidev0.0"):
    with Lepton() as l:
      a,_ = l.capture()     #grab the buffer
    cv2.normalize(a, a, 0, 65535, cv2.NORM_MINMAX) # extend  contrast
    np.right_shift(a, 8, a) # fit data into 8 bits
    return np.uint8(a)


#Create a window and give it features
def nothing(x):
    pass
cv2.namedWindow('flir', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.moveWindow('flir',1,1)
cv2.createTrackbar('thresh','flir',50,100,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('erode','flir',5,100,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('dilate','flir',7,100,nothing)

#process the buffer into an image on a continuous loop    
while True:

    #update the image processing variables
    thresh = cv2.getTrackbarPos('thresh', 'flir')
    erodeSize = cv2.getTrackbarPos('erode', 'flir')
    dilateSize = cv2.getTrackbarPos('dilate', 'flir')

    image = capture()

    #apply some image processing
    blurredBrightness = cv2.bilateralFilter(image,9,150,150)
    thresh = 50
    edges = cv2.Canny(blurredBrightness,thresh,thresh*2, L2gradient=True)
    _,mask = cv2.threshold(blurredBrightness,200,1,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    erodeSize = 5
    dilateSize = 14
    eroded = cv2.erode(mask, np.ones((erodeSize, erodeSize)))
    mask = cv2.dilate(eroded, np.ones((dilateSize, dilateSize)))
    adjusted_image = cv2.resize(cv2.cvtColor(mask*edges, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB) | image, (640, 4$
    final_image = cv2.applyColorMap(adjusted_image, cv2.COLORMAP_HOT)

    #display the image
    cv2.imshow('flir', final_image)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyWindow('flir')
```

Comment: You have a `while True` so it close the window at the end of the loop and then starts over from the beginning of the while block. It will do this forever!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, Calm down.

Secondly, look at your code closely. Closing the window wouldn't do you any good, because of the lines:

`cv2.imshow('flir', final_image)`
and

```
cv2.destroyWindow('flir')
```

What these 2 are doing in tandem is that you're displaying a frame in a new window, and then destroying it, then recreating that window in `imshow`, then displaying the next frame and destroying it...and so on and so forth.

That should explain your flickering windows.

To stop execution of your program, you've added this code:

```
 if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
```

What this implies is that when you press 'q' on your keyboard while your image window is in focus, your while loop will break and your program will terminate.

So I would advise you to remove `cv2.destroyWindow` and use 'q' key to quit your application than to close it using your mouse.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer. Sorry for the drama. It was 2am at that point, and I was frustrated.